# How to get the value of button when clicked using vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I have several buttons on a page which are hooked to the same method `webcamSendRequestButton`

```
<button v-on:click="webcamSendRequestButton" value="0" type="button" class="webcam-send-request-button" :disabled="disabled">Verify</button>
<button v-on:click="webcamSendRequestButton" value="1" type="button" class="webcam-send-request-button" :disabled="disabled">Verify</button>
<button v-on:click="webcamSendRequestButton" value="2" type="button" class="webcam-send-request-button" :disabled="disabled">Verify</button>
<button v-on:click="webcamSendRequestButton" value="3" type="button" class="webcam-send-request-button" :disabled="disabled">Verify</button>
```

and I am making an ajax call when the button is clicked. In jquery or JS it is pretty straightforward to get the value of button when clicked using `$(this).val();`

How do I fetch the value of the button when it is clicked in vue?

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#my-div',
    methods: {
        webcamSendRequestButton: function() {

            const buttonValue = ??? // How do I fetch the value over here

            $.ajax({
                url: "someurl",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    value: buttonValue
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    // Omitted for brevity
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can simply give it as an argument to the function.

```
<button v-on:click="webcamSendRequestButton(0)"  type="button" class="webcam-send-request-button" :disabled="disabled">Verify</button>
```

JS

```
...
methods: {
  webcamSendRequestButton(value){
     //"value" is the clicked button value
  }
}
...
```

Answer (score 30):

A better answer than the previous ones I believe is to inject the original DOM '`$event`' variable into your handler call:

`v-on:click="webcamSendRequestButton($event)"`

And receive it in your handler:

```
methods: {
  webcamSendRequestButton: function(e) {
    const buttonValue = e.target.value;
    .
    .
    .
  }
}
```

This is better for two well-connected reasons.

**First**, the code now has the same reasoning behind the initial intention: When a button is clicked, the handler should be able to read the value of the button that initiated the event. Other solutions that pass the value statically to the handler only *mimic* this, thus being more or less a hack.

**Second**, because the code now exactly matches the initial intention, the code becomes more maintainable. For example, if the value of each button gets to change dynamically by being bound to a variable value instead of a static value, the handler needs not to be changed at all. If the buttons grow or shrink in number, there is no need to change the handler code or define extra references or change the syntax of the handler call.

Comment: It doesn't work. I can not see the `buttonValue` passed to the data method in the ajax call. The whole object is missing from the header `value: buttonValue`. The solution which works is the accepted one.

Comment: If you do `console.log(e.target.value)` at the top of the handler's code, do you get the correct value? Have you tried using the `native` modifier for your `v-on:click` directive making it `v-on:click.native`?

Comment: I know the accepted answer works, but if the value of the button no longer is statically supplied to the view itself as a literal number, and instead become dynamic as the value of a variable, that method won't work anymore. You might find this required.

Comment: Ok, Some more update. It works on the first fired event only. For e.g if I click on a button with value="1" it sends `value: 1`. If I click another button the object is gone. However, it should send `value: 2`

Comment: You perhaps forgot to add `$event` as an argument for all your buttons in the `v-on:click` handler call  just like you did with the first one.

Comment: I have `$event` arg on all the buttons. The event is fired up randomly. See the screenshot http://imgur.com/a/dTiAi. Sometimes, clicking multiple times on the buttons fires up the event with button value and sometimes returns undefined.

Comment: That is strange. If you make a JSFiddle I can take a look and give you further help.

Comment: Technically it should work as seen here https://jsfiddle.net/o3kgwvrx/ but I am not sure the same code does not work in my app.

Comment: Yup; The JSFiddle works fine, which is why it is strange that it doesn't in your code. If I add a `.native` modifier to the code in the JSFiddle it stops working, so if that's also your case try removing `.native`.

Comment: I didn't add `.native` at the first place. Anyway, your solution for the general issue works fine. Why is it not working in my code base is my problem to solve. Thanks!

Comment: Could you explain in your answer *why* you think this is a better answer? This is a very atypical approach in Vue in my experience.

Comment: @Bert: Done! Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

You can give your button a reference that Vue can access by giving it a tag `ref="yourRef"`. Then you can access the value inside of your called function with `this.$refs.yourRef.value`.

Works for other Input elements as well ;)

Answer (score 1):

I have a button group, and three buttons in it. I wanted to get the string from each button button when there is a change, and change my attribute to that string value when there is a change in button. I used `@change` event of `vuejs` and it worked for me. I will be pleased if it will be helpful for someone else too.

**In template:**

```
    <div class="btn-group">
      <button
        type="button"
        class="btn btn-md light btn__border"
        v-on:change="latestType = 'week'"
      >Week</button>
      <button
        type="button"
        class="btn btn-md light btn__border"
        v-on:change="latestType = 'month'"
      >Month</button>
      <button
        type="button"
        class="btn btn-md light btn__border"
        v-on:change="latestType = ''"
      >All</button>
    </div>
```

**In Js (script tag):**

```
...
data() {
  return {
    latestType:''
  }
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

One improvement over the accepted answer by reinarg is to access the button's value directly using `event.srcElement`. This way you don't have to pass an argument into `webcamSendRequestButton` in the template. In fact, the OP wouldn't have to change the template at all and would have to change only one thing in the method:

```
webcamSendRequestButton: function() {

    const buttonValue = event.srcElement.value // This provides the button's value

    $.ajax({
        url: "someurl",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            value: buttonValue
        },
        success: function (data) {
            // Omitted for brevity
        }
    });
}
```

This also avoids having to enter the same value in two places for each button (once in the `value` attribute and again as an argument for the `webcamSendRequestButton` method).