# Vuejs get attribute from button

Tags: vue.js

I would like to have attribute `tblid` from `button` element, when click event is triggered.

I was reading questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45978055/how-to-get-the-value-of-button-when-clicked-using-vue-js), but it's not working for me -> example below.

What seems so strange to me is that `e.target` or `e.currentTarget` returns the element with all attributes, including `tblid`. Why is so hard in vuejs to get those attributes from element?

Please note: I know I can create component and use props on that component. But I really don't want to create component for every html element like button, label, input ...

html:

```
<div id="app">
      <button tblid="tbl1" @click="buttonClick($event)">
        Button 1 tbl1
      </button>
    </div>
```

app.js:

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  methods: {
      buttonClick(e){
          debugger;
      }
  }
});
```

[image]

Comment: Vue does not blindly pollute the DOM. Adding every single attribute of a VNode element to the DOM element would decrease the performance of the DOM considerably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the value of tblid you could just send that as parameter in the even listener function instead of using the event object.

```js
<button tblid="tbl1" @click="buttonClick('tbl1')">
    Button 1 tbl1
</button>
```

Comment: Getting attribute is not possible?

Comment: If you really want to you could try by adding a data-attribute somethine like `data-tblid` and in the elements object you can access like evt.target.dataset.tblid

Comment: well I think adding the parameter directly to the event listener might be more vue style, both as long as both methods work its okay to use whichever you prefer I guess.

Comment: Thanks for answers. You were very helpful - I've also discovered that I can use e.currentTarget.getAttribute('attr_name').